# Mongo type-insensitive find() for numeric strings

Tags: mongodb

Is there any way to find documents by a field that is numeric but not necessarily stored as a number?

Here's an example collection.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b606fe0f73e7e0f3c263439"), "some_num" : "123" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b606fe1f73e7e1b3f37a8f0"), "some_num" : 456 }
```

I want to be able to do the following, or close to it.

```
db.my_collection.find({ some_num: 123 })
db.my_collection.find({ some_num: "456" })
```

As it is, I have to know the type that's stored in the db before I can query for it. Do I have to go the regex path, or is there some $special_option for this use?